# Gravity.CENTER in GridLayout is not working

Tags: android

This is the XML that work fine, when I run in Android Studio, how to make this programmatically?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.test.MainActivity">
        <TextView
            android:text="Texto 1"/>

</GridLayout>
```

This is the code, that I try to make without success...

```
//TODO create Grid params
GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
gridParams.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
gridParams.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
//TODO set gravity to CENTER
gridParams.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

//TODO create GridLayout
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(context);
//TODO set Grid Params
gridLayout.setLayoutParams(gridParams);

//TODO create TextView
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("Text 1");
//TODO add to Grid
gridLayout.addView(textView);

setContentView(gridLayout);
```

Android Studio version 2.3.3
Tested in Tablet running Android 4.2.2

EDIT Working

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
RelativeLayout parentRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
parentRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
parentRelativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
parentRelativeLayout.addView(gridLayout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grid layout needs to be inside another layout like `RelativeLayout` that has a width and height of match parent.

Its not that it isn't working, just think of it like this, the gridLayout is only big enough to contain its own containers, which isn't the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
gridParams.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
gridParams.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
params.weight=1.0f;
```

//TODO create Grid params